# Search and append text at the end of the line

Tags: vim

I have a file in which there is a command on each line. Within the command there is a line which is always `P0......xml`. I want to append that `P0....` to the end of each line with a `>>` operator in front and `.log` at the end.

For example,
If a command looks like this:

```
abcdefg hijkl mno P0qrstuv.xml wxyz abc
```

I would like to make it:

```
abcdefg hijkl mno P0qrstuv.xml wxyz abc >> P0qrstuv.log
```

Please explain your answer as precisely as possible.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to use the substitute command in Ex mode. This should do it.

```
:%s/\v(P0.+\.xml).*/& >>\1.log/
```

`:` puts you into Ex mode

`%` act on the whole file

`s` does the substitution

`\v` specifies that the regex will "very magic" and not the regular vim regex.

`(P0.+\.xml)` grouping of text the file name

`&` inserts what was matched

`\1` inserts the first grouping (if you would have more than one you could do \2 \3 etc..)

Comment: I believe you want `%s/\v((P0.+)\.xml).*/& >>\2.log/`